# Не срабатывает валидатор и не отображается сообщение об ошибке в django

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, связанная с моделью:

```
class paidparkingForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = paidparking
      fields = ['adress','carnumber','amountoftime', 'price', 'email','telephone', 'startofvalidityperiod', 'expirationdate']
      widgets = {
          'adress': forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control form", "id": "exampleFormControlSelect1"}),
          'carnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
          'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form", "readonly": 0}),
          'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
          'telephone': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
      }
```

Импортировал import re и from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

Добавил валидатор

```
  def clean_telephone(self):
      telephone = self.cleaned_data['telephone']
      if re.match('^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$', telephone):
          raise forms.ValidationError('Телефон должен иметь формат  891665283219')
      return telephone
```

Валидатор не срабатывает и не выводит никаких ошибок

На страницу вывожу вот так

```
                                    <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Номер телефона</h5>
    <label for="{{ formparking.telephone.id_for_label }}"></label>
      {{ formparking.telephone }}
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {{ formparking.telephone.errors }}
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали в виджетах валидатор.

```
forms.CharField(validators=[clean_telephone])
```

Comment: Получил следующую ошибку: name 'validators' is not defined. Нужно как-то подключить?

Comment: В вашем случае необходимо указать ваш валидатор.

Comment: Подключил вот таким образом           'telephone': forms.CharField(validators=[clean_telephone],attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),. У меня валидатор находится после формы, но выдается ошибка name 'clean_telephone' is not defined

Comment: Для вас имеет значение где он будет находиться? Сверху или сниху?

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/validators.html

Comment: Сделал так, как вы сказали           'telephone': forms.CharField(validators=[clean_telephone]),. Теперь столкнулся со следующей ошибкой 'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'. Нужно добавить какой-то атрибут?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос), оформляйте. Добавляейте код.